# Hebrew characters can't be used when renaming files

Tags: powershell, character-encoding

I'm trying to use the following code:

```
ls *.xml | Foreach {$i=1} {
  $nonParsedXML =  $_
  [xml]$parsedXML = Get-Content $nonParsedXML -Encoding utf8
  $title = $parsedXML.title
  $nonParsedXMLwithExtension = "$($title).xml"
  Rename-Item $nonParsedXML -NewName $nonParsedXMLwithExtension
}
```

The code tries to rename a file, and the new name is the content of a tag within the files. It works when the content of the tag is in English, but it doesn't work correctly when the content is in Hebrew - The code is renaming the file, but instead of Hebrew characters I see block characters.

In case you wonder, the problem occurs when I'm using PowerShell ISE.
When I'm using PowerShell in the command prompt, the code can't be run because it can't handle the Hebrew characters at all and produces errors.

Could you please clarify this issue? Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very nice and helpful guy gave me the solution. Here it is:

---

```
dir -Path C:\Temp\Test -Filter *.xml | ForEach-Object {
  $xml = [xml](Get-Content -Path $_.FullName -Encoding UTF8)
  Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "$($xml.title).xml"
}
```

---

Answer (score 1):

It seems like default file charset, try to change it to extended charset.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/default-utf-8-encoding-for-new-notepad-documents/525f0ae7-121e-4eac-a6c2-cfe6b498712c

I hope that this article will help you.

Comment: Hi Tomer, the files in question were already saved in UTF-8 when the script tried to manipulate them. Can you think of something else that might cause this issue?

Thanks in advance